# Regular expression with multiline block of text (python)

Tags: python, regex, list, split, expression

I have the following file named seq.fasta:

```
>AAM15934.1| NtrX [Gluconacetobacter diazotrophicus]| NTRX1 | Response_reg - Sigma54_activat - HTH_8
MGHEILIVDDEPDIRLLVEGILRDEGYETRLAGDSDSAISAFRARRPSLVILDVWLQGSRLDGLGILQAI
QGEEPVVPTIMISGHGTIETAVAALQHGAYDFIEKPFQSDRLLLVVRRALEASRLARENAELRLRAGPEA
MLYGDSPVIAGVRNQIERVAPSGSRVLISGAAGAGKEVAARMIHARSPGPKAFIALNCATLAPGRFEEEL
FGIEGAPDGTGRRTGVLERAHGGTLLLDEVSDMPIETQGKIVRALQDQSFERVGGASRVKVDVRVLAATN
RDLQEAIAAGRFREDLYYRLAVVPLRVPSLRERREDIPGLARLFLRRAAENAGLPLRDLSGDAVAALQSY
DWPGNARELRNLMERLLIMMPGNGSDLIRAEMLPPSVGQGAPALLKFDPAADVMGLPLREARDLFETQYL
QAQLLRFGGNISRTAGFVGMERSALHRKLKQLGVTSEERGAG

>WP_002731145.1| NtrX [Phaeospirillum molischianum]| NTRX1 | Response_reg - Sigma54_activat - HTH_8
MAHDILIVDDEADIRVLIAGILEDEGHSTREAANADEALERIRARRPSLVIQDIWLQGSRLDGLGVLDEI
KREHPDVPVVMISGHGTIETAVQAIKQGAYDFIEKPFKADRLLLVVDRAIESARLKRENQELRVRSGSTG
DLVGISPALVQIRQTIERVAPTNSRVLITGPAGSGKEVAARMIHAHSRRTEGPFVVVNCAAMHPDRMEIE
LFGTEYGADGSTSPRKIGTFEQAHSGTLLLDEVADMPLETQGKIVRVLQDQTFERVGGGKRVEVDVRVIA
TTNRDLQSEMIAGHFREDLFYRLNVVPIRMPALRDGKEDIPLLARQFMQLAAQLAGVPPRPLGEDALAAL
QAYDWPGNVRQLRNAIDWLLIMAPGDWRDPVRADMLPSEIGAITPAVLRWEKSSEIMTLPLREARELFER
EYLLAQVNRFAGNISRTAAFVGMERSALHRKLKLLGINTDEKVR

>WP_002967695.1| NtrX  [Brucella abortus]| NTRX1 | Response_reg - Sigma54_activat - HTH_8
MAADILVVDDEVDIRDLVAGILSDEGHETRTAFDADSALAAINDRAPRLVFLDIWLQGSRLDGLALLDEI
KKQHPELPVVMISGHGNIETAVSAIRRGAYDFIEKPFKADRLILVAERALETSKLKREVSDLRKRTGDQL
ELVGTSLAMNQLRQTIERVAPTNSRIMITGPSGAGKELVARTIHAQSSRANGPFVTVNAATITPERMEIE
LFGTEMDGGERKVGALEEAHGGILYLDEVADMPRETQNKILRVLVDQQFERVGGTKRVKVDVRIISSTAQ
NLEGMIAEGTFREDLFHRLSVVPVQVPALAARREDIPSLVEFFMKQIAEQAGIKPRKIGPDAMAVLQAHS
WPGNLRQLRNNVERLMILTRGDDPDELVTADLLPAEIGDTLPRAPTESDQHIMALPLREARERFEKEYLI
AQINRFGGNISRTAEFVGMERSALHRKLKSLGV
```

I want to put each block of letters in a list.
Example:

List Contents:

```
List[0] = MGHEILIVDDEPDIRLLVEGILRDEGYETRLAGDSDSAISAFRARRPSLVILDVWLQGSRLDGLGILQAI
QGEEPVVPTIMISGHGTIETAVAALQHGAYDFIEKPFQSDRLLLVVRRALEASRLARENAELRLRAGPEA
MLYGDSPVIAGVRNQIERVAPSGSRVLISGAAGAGKEVAARMIHARSPGPKAFIALNCATLAPGRFEEEL
FGIEGAPDGTGRRTGVLERAHGGTLLLDEVSDMPIETQGKIVRALQDQSFERVGGASRVKVDVRVLAATN
RDLQEAIAAGRFREDLYYRLAVVPLRVPSLRERREDIPGLARLFLRRAAENAGLPLRDLSGDAVAALQSY
DWPGNARELRNLMERLLIMMPGNGSDLIRAEMLPPSVGQGAPALLKFDPAADVMGLPLREARDLFETQYL
QAQLLRFGGNISRTAGFVGMERSALHRKLKQLGVTSEERGAG

List[1] = MAHDILIVDDEADIRVLIAGILEDEGHSTREAANADEALERIRARRPSLVIQDIWLQGSRLDGLGVLDEI
KREHPDVPVVMISGHGTIETAVQAIKQGAYDFIEKPFKADRLLLVVDRAIESARLKRENQELRVRSGSTG
DLVGISPALVQIRQTIERVAPTNSRVLITGPAGSGKEVAARMIHAHSRRTEGPFVVVNCAAMHPDRMEIE
LFGTEYGADGSTSPRKIGTFEQAHSGTLLLDEVADMPLETQGKIVRVLQDQTFERVGGGKRVEVDVRVIA
TTNRDLQSEMIAGHFREDLFYRLNVVPIRMPALRDGKEDIPLLARQFMQLAAQLAGVPPRPLGEDALAAL
QAYDWPGNVRQLRNAIDWLLIMAPGDWRDPVRADMLPSEIGAITPAVLRWEKSSEIMTLPLREARELFER
EYLLAQVNRFAGNISRTAAFVGMERSALHRKLKLLGINTDEKVR

List[2] = MAADILVVDDEVDIRDLVAGILSDEGHETRTAFDADSALAAINDRAPRLVFLDIWLQGSRLDGLALLDEI
KKQHPELPVVMISGHGNIETAVSAIRRGAYDFIEKPFKADRLILVAERALETSKLKREVSDLRKRTGDQL
ELVGTSLAMNQLRQTIERVAPTNSRIMITGPSGAGKELVARTIHAQSSRANGPFVTVNAATITPERMEIE
LFGTEMDGGERKVGALEEAHGGILYLDEVADMPRETQNKILRVLVDQQFERVGGTKRVKVDVRIISSTAQ
NLEGMIAEGTFREDLFHRLSVVPVQVPALAARREDIPSLVEFFMKQIAEQAGIKPRKIGPDAMAVLQAHS
WPGNLRQLRNNVERLMILTRGDDPDELVTADLLPAEIGDTLPRAPTESDQHIMALPLREARERFEKEYLI
AQINRFGGNISRTAEFVGMERSALHRKLKSLGV
```

But i'm struggling to split and put them in a list, my code is like:

```
import re

myfile = open('seq.fasta', 'r').read()

regex = re.compile(r'^>([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]([A-Z\n\r]+)', re.MULTILINE)
matches = [m.groups() for m in regex.finditer(myfile)]

for m in matches:
    onlySequences = (m[1])

print(onlySequences)
```

The variable `onlySequences` returns just the last one block of letters, how do i keep all of them, each one in a number of a list?

Comment: You re-write `onlySequences` each time when you iterate over `matches`.

Comment: You don't need regex to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `onlySequences` within for loop. Perhaps you only need this:

```
matches = [m.groups()[1] for m in regex.finditer(myfile)]
print(matches)
```

Or correction in your code:

```
matches = [m.groups() for m in regex.finditer(myfile)]
onlySequences = [m[1] for m in matches]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do that. A better way consists to read the file line by line:

```
with open('seq.fasta', 'r') as fh:
    result = []
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            temp = ''
        elif not line.strip():
            result.append(temp)
        else:
            temp = temp + line

    if temp:
        result.append(temp)

    print("\n".join(result))
```